# Sending email using google javascript API bounces

Tags: javascript, email, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to use the JS google API to send emails. The initialization goes well, but when I try to send an email, it bounces back saying "An error occurred. Your message was not sent" without any additional data.

My code for sending a test email:

```
let email = 'To:luoruize@gmail.com\r\n';
email += 'Subject:Testing\r\n';
email += 'This is a test!';

const message = window.btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    userId: 'me',
    resource: {
        raw: message
    }
}).execute((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js) to familiarize on how to set up Gmail API, OAuth 2.0 Authentication and basic flow of the cade sample given by Google. I also found a tutorial for [Sending Emails with the Gmail JavaScript API](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-gmail-javascript-api/), the tutorial also provide a detailed from enabling your API to the initial setup then sending an email. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the problem is that there has to be an extra \r\n before the content...